# How can I verify a custom domain on Azure AD

Tags: azure-devops, dns, azure-active-directory, subdomain

I am trying to verify a custom domain on azure by adding a TX record at my registrar.  I get this strange message (see bottom of image):

[image: Error Message]

What can this mean and how can it be fixed?

It had just occurred to me that I do have CNAME records for this domain that connect to Azure Static Web Sites to sub domains on this domain.  Can this be a problem?

Comment: It means that the custom domain is in use in another Azure AD. You can't verify a domain on two Azure AD tenants.

Comment: Thanks, but that is impossible, or very strange.  I own the domain and I only have one AD.  Did you see the comment I added about CNAME records?

Comment: @juunas do you know what is cqearlyaccess.onmicrosoft.com ?

Comment: No idea. Someone has created that tenant and added the custom domain to it. If you check https://login.microsoftonline.com/cqearlyaccess.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration, you can see the tenant id `902ac721-1061-4664-bf29-f24d3aef5c38`. If you replace the cqearlyaccess.onmicrosoft.com in the URL with your domain, you can verify if it has the same tenant id (and that it exists).

Comment: Wow, it must have been be me, when I was trying to follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain.  My error may have been that I published the microsoft-identity-association.json to a subdomain rather than to the domain itself.  What a mess.  Do you think it is reversible?

Comment: If you have access to that Azure AD tenant, you can switch to it in Azure Portal and remove the custom domain there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when the domain name has been registered to another Azure AD tenant already.
You can only verify a domain in one Azure AD tenant as the domain can be used to identify an Azure AD tenant.

You'll need to find out if you can access that tenant through Azure Portal, or if someone else in your organization can.
Otherwise it'll probably be a Microsoft support ticket.

Note: if you are trying to verify a sub-domain, you need to register the sub-domain first in tenant A before registering the parent domain in tenant B.
After registering the parent domain, you won't be able to register its sub-domains in other tenants either.

Comment: Have done some more reading and I don't think this tenant was directly created by me, rather Azure added my domain to it when I used the early access feature of Email one-time Password.  Obviously I don't have access to that tenant and it bugs me to have to pay for support to fix their error...